# Grabbing one item out of an array in the VUEX store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

This is my first time diving into vuex, and so far it is going well! I have been able to store a list of "projects" and display them on my home page.

However, I am a bit stuck as to how to interact with the stored array on another page.

Currently, I have 3 projects "project 1, project 2 and project 3". I display all of them on my home page in a list, and clicking one sends me to "www.mywebsite.com/project-1".

My question is, how do i go into my state and grab just "project 1" from the object? Or, I guess, a better question is how do i reference the stored state to do stuff/use it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a getter

e.g.,

```js
state: {
  projects: [{id: 'project 1', ... }, {id: 'project 2', ...} , {id: 'project 3', ...}],
};
getters: {
  getbyId(state) {
    return (id) => state.projects.find(project => project.id === id);
  },
};
```

Then in your in your implementation

```js
const project = this.$store.getters.getById('project 1');
```